# Sending an Email from a python script without a from address

Tags: python, dataframe, email

So I have seen lots of great info on here about sending automated emails using python. However, my task is slightly different. The script im working on needs to send an automated email when some condition is true then the email contains the printed output. But since this is for work the file is stored on a shared server and therefore, I cannot be the one to "send" the email, it needs to send automatically from the file. My question is therefore how this email can be sent with no "from" address, or if this is even possible.

Additionally, how can I make sure that the email contains the printed output? Below is the attached code im using. The variables stored in the list are dataframes.

```
mylist = [right_branchcode, right_branchname, right_sellingcode, right_advcorp, right_childparent, \
          right_eliteCategoryId, right_partyid, right_retailmga]

flag = True
for item in mylist:
    if len(item) > 0:
        print(item)
        flag = True          
    else:
        pass

def send_email(audit):
    fromaddr = " >"
    toaddr = "recip@mail, recip2@mail"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Alert: Audit Mismatch For DimAdvisor"
    body = "Current mismatch in dimAdvisor found on : " + temperature
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "password")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simply using an obviously invalid address in the "from" field (e.g., **noreply@nowhere**). As for the second part of your question, you need to construct the mail's content through some specific method. Just using what's printed on the console is both not a good idea, and kind of difficult to do.

Comment: What kind of specific method would that be? I do have the ability to use an excel spreadsheet which populated with the data?

Comment: Hi, in your code above there is no section of creating or sending an email...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can send email using `Python`:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk']
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = "Can be any string you want, use ASCII chars only " # sender name
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients) # for one recipient just enter a valid email address
msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
body = "message body"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)  # put your relevant SMTP here

server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login('jhon@gmail.com', '1234567890')  # use your real gmail account user name and password
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Please note this line:

```
msg['From'] = "Can be any string you want, use ASCII chars only " # sender name
```

You can write any string in the `From` field regardless of any real email address. I didn't try to leave it empty but I guess you can try it yourself :-)